# Consulta relacion tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelorelacional

Me podran ayudar respecto a la relacion entre 2 tablas en SQL Server?

### Tabla 1

```
ID_PAIS (**PK**)

NOMBRE_PAIS
```

### Tabla 2

```
ID_TURISTA (**PK**)

CANTIDAD_TURISTAS

NUM_TRIMESTRE

AÑO 

ID_PAIS INGRESO (**FK**)

ID_PAIS EGRESO (**FK**)
```

Se pueden establecer estas dos relaciones FK?
El campo de relación es ID_PAIS, solo que lo utilizaría para diferentes cosas (ingresos y egresos de turistas).

Gracias!!!

Comment: Si, absolutamente.

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu aporte!!!

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta de Patricio, claro que se puede. Sólo ten cuidado. Con tu estructura me estás diciendo que un turista puede tener **sólo un país de ingreso y un país de egreso en CUALQUIER momento**. Si es un turista paseando a través de la unión europea y quieres saber cuáles países visitó, y en qué orden, te conviene tener una tabla `Turista_Pais`.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer '[cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' en nuestro centro de ayuda, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y evites respuestas de tipo *Sí y/o No*, como esta; porque la respuesta de Patricio **ES**, aunque estés en desacuerdo, una respuesta **válida y completa para tu pregunta**

Comment: @Arriel Gracias por tu ayuda. En este caso solo necesito saber CANTIDAD de turistas que ingresaron a argentina (de que pais) y que cantidad egresaron de argentina a otros países.

Estaria bien de esa manera o me convendría hacer otra tabla?

Comment: En ese caso, tu segunda tabla es ambigua... si tiene ID_TURISTA, que tiene CANTIDAD_TURISTAS? me parece que vos queres una tabla de agrupacion.. y en ese caso, ese id me sobra.. o es otra cosa?

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Te invito a que uses http://sqlfiddle.com/ para que publiques correctamente tus preguntas sobre bases de datos.